# QGIS (python) action to open folder and search for string

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I am using QGIS layer property actions. Is it possible for python to open windows explorer at a directory and then search for a custom string?

Currently I can open windows explorer at the directory I want using:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /search, "D:\GIS\Infrastructure"')
```

But how would I search for a custom string `([%Hospital%]` column in attribute file), i.e. open `D:\GIS\Infrastructure` and list all files that have the word "Hospital" in (as if I was to enter "Hospital" into the search bar of the folder)

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a GIS question, but a question about windows explorer, so it is probably better suited to another site. I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/499238/command-to-open-windows-explorer-window-with-filtered-results/1177021#1177021) after a quick search. That would probably be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

One option you could use is os.walk and .find string method:

```
import os
searchDirectory = 'C:/Temp'
searchFor = 'Hospital'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchDirectory):
    for f in files:
        found = f.find(searchFor)
        if found > -1:
            print root + '//' + f
```